# Laptop not booting after Ubuntu install

Tags: boot, 18.04, uefi, bios

I don't know if this is the correct forum to ask this question but I'll still ask. I was using Windows 10 on my laptop (Dell 5547). I am a newbie to Ubuntu installation. I formatted the drive and installed Ubuntu 18.04. Everything worked fine for some time then the it just got stuck. I did a hard reboot and since then I'm unable to boot my Laptop. I think this might be a BIOS issue. Can anybody guide me to a solution?

Edit: This is not a dual boot. I removed windows and installed Ubuntu. After turning it on, i can hear the fan and the system lights turn on but nothing on the screen, but it dies after 2 seconds.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is not a discussion forum but a question and answer site. This is the right place for this question. However, we need more information. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1125042/edit) the question above and add what happens when you try to boot your laptop. Also indicate if it still has Windows 10 (that is, is it dual boot?). Add all error messages in the question. If you can take a picture, upload the picture at imgur.com and add the link to the uploaded picture in the question above.

Comment: No it is not a dual boot. When I turn it on I get a blank screen and i can hear the fan running and the lights turn but the screen remains blank. However, it dies after 2 seconds.

Comment: Please edit your question and add these details. When you say the "the screen remains blank" do you mean a **black** screen? Do you see a blinking cursor or a mouse pointer? Before the black screen do you see any lines of text? Can you get to the BIOS settings menu by pressing whatever key you need to press to get to the BIOS?

Comment: I will edit the question. No there is nothing on the screen. It's black.

Comment: If you can't get to the BIOS setup screen, then something is wrong with your hardware, such as, hard disk, RAM, or the CPU. It has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you sure? Because it was working fine since years. Never had a problem. It froze the last time i used it and then hard restarting it let to this situation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90936/discussion-between-user68186-and-ali-turab-abbasi).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be related to hardware breakdown.